# Opening files into an existing vim session (Cygwin/mintty)

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, mintty

I am looking for ideas to open files into an existing vim session.

I am working on Windows + Cygwin + Mintty. I usually have 3 to 4 opened terminals (2-3 vim sessions + 1 shell, build environment). I don't use tmux/screen because it's easier to use the native Windows's window manager to switch in between my terminal windows. Because I have 2 wide-screen monitors I can use the 2 half of both screens for my terminals which gives me an awesome working environment. With the help of an [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, I can use shortcuts to switch/rotate or even to reposition my terminals in the desired position.

I rather prefer vim over gvim for many reasons. I can achieve almost all the gvim features (scroll, mouse selection,  copy,  paste, etc. I am one of those who think that using the respectable y/P commands is a bit crippling when you need to use plenty of other softwares that use /. I always get confused to use different shortcuts for each software I am using.

Now the core issue. I would like to open a file from the Windows explorer into an existing vim session. I found a horrible solution using a Perl script with the Win32::API in order to look for an existing mintty terminal with `Vim` in the title. Then I activate the window and send `<esc>:e path/file<cr>` to it.

It works pretty well but I am looking for a better solution like `gvim --remote` that works with my console `vim`. Unfortunately I don't have such options with my vim even though if I built it with the `-with-x` configure option.

So, I am looking for some suggestions to achieve a more honorable solution (socket/adding the feature directly to vim/using a smarter ahk script/etc.)

Comment: What do you mean `send <esc>:e path/file<cr> to it`? What is `send` and what is `it`?

Comment: If you enable the focus of the mintty windows that runs vim through the User32.dll you can then send keystrokes to the vim session. Thus you can open the document you want to open as if you have typed `:e <path to the file you want to edit>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gvim --remote` should work with console vim if you start vim with `vim --servername GVIM`. Alternatively, choose another servername and use `vim --servername foo --remote`.

Comment: I don't have the `--servername` option with my vim